# Does the datetime.datetime.ctime() function return a fixed width string?

Tags: python, datetime

If I were to run the following code:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
date_str = dt.ctime()
```

Will the result of `len(date_str)` always be the same, regardless of when I happen to run the code?  I *think* it will be, but I'm not certain. I looked at the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) reference but the relevant section says:

> Return a string representing the date:
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import date
> >>> date(2002, 12, 4).ctime()
> 'Wed Dec  4 00:00:00 2002'
> ```
>
> `d.ctime()` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> time.ctime(time.mktime(d.timetuple()))
> ```
>
> on platforms where the native C ctime() function (which time.ctime() invokes, but which date.ctime() does not invoke) conforms to the C standard.

But looking at the article on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime), the answer is less than clear to me. I did find a reference [here](https://pythontic.com/datetime/date/ctime) which suggests that it will be a 24-character wide string, but I was hoping for a more official source or reference if possible. It's possible that I didn't delve far enough into the C-standard to divine the answer.

Also, based on that quote, does that mean the behavior might be platform-dependent?  Or is it likely to be generally uniform outside of niche operating systems?

(yes I know that I can manually format to fixed-width, but I want to know whether the built-in one already is that way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed-width. You can see in the cppreference article you linked that the output of C `ctime` follows the format

```
Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy\n
```

which is fixed-width. (Python doesn't include the trailing `\n`, but it's still fixed-width.)

You can also check the [C standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.2) directly and find that the standard-mandated output is fixed-width.

You can also check the [implementation of `datetime.ctime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L5612) if you want to be extra sure.

> Also, based on that quote, does that mean the behavior might be platform-dependent?

No. The behavior is platform-independent. The quote is saying that `datetime.ctime` behaves like the C standard mandated behavior of the C `ctime` function, even if the platform implementation of the C function does not conform to the C standard.

Comment: It looks like I should've gone one layer deeper: the `asctime` on cppreference explicitly states that it returns the string in a "[fixed 25-character form](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime)".

Answer (score 2):

I've looked up `datetime` in the source code of [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/datetime.py) on github. It is implemented as this:

```py
    def ctime(self):
        "Return ctime() style string."
        weekday = self.toordinal() % 7 or 7
        return "%s %s %2d 00:00:00 %04d" % (
            _DAYNAMES[weekday],
            _MONTHNAMES[self._month],
            self._day, self._year)
```

with `_DAYNAMES` and `_MONTHNAMES` being:

```py
_MONTHNAMES = [None, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                     "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
_DAYNAMES = [None, "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
```

So I would think the length will always be the same. The only exception that I can think of is when `weekday` and `self._month` are set at 0, making them return `None`. Rather than a 3-string word, it returns a 4-string word in those cases. But since you always will use `datetime.now()`, this shouldn't be of any concern.

Comment: That's the pure-Python version of `datetime`, which isn't the version that gets used in most cases. It gets overridden by the `from _datetime import *` at the bottom of the file, which loads definitions from the C `_datetime` module.

Comment: The `_datetime` implementation of `datetime.ctime` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L5612).

Answer (score 1):

Well, `cppreference` clearly states that the C standard requires `ctime` to return a 25 characters strings ending with a newline.

> The resulting string has the following format:
>
> ```
> Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy\n
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The function does not support localization.

The doc for the `time` module states (emphasize mine):

> Most of the functions defined in this module call platform C library functions with the same name.

A `ctime` is required by C standard, it should be available on any platform. So it should be always used by `time.ctime`.

Let us go on:

> **`time.ctime([secs])`**
>
> ...
>
> If secs is not provided or None, the current time as returned by `time()` is used. **`ctime(secs)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(secs))`**. Locale information is not used by ctime().

and

> **`time.asctime([t])`**
>
> Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by `gmtime()` or `localtime()` to a string of the following form: `'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993'`. The day field is two characters long and is space padded if the day is a single digit, e.g.: `'Wed Jun  9 04:26:40 1993'`.
> ...
> Note:
> Unlike the C function of the same name, `asctime()` does not add a trailing newline.

So instead of the 25 characters string returned by the C function, the `ctime` or `asctime` functions of the Python standard library `time` module return a non localized 24 characters string.

So if you use CPython, and except on a specific system where the C standard library would be non conformant, you can trust `time.ctime` to always return a 24 character string.

And even if you use a different implementation (Jython, PyPy, etc.) the Python standard library documentation states that this non localized 24 characters string should be returned. So I cannot imagine a system returning a different size...